# Extensão para Chrome + Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extensão

Gostaria de dicas para desenvolver extensões para o *Chorme*(e outros navegadores) usando *NodesJS*. Porque *NodeJS*? Bem eu gostaria de dar uma certa proteção aos meus códigos JS para que não ficassem visível ou sujeito a alteração, tenho um conhecimento iniciante em *dev* de extensões e em *NodeJS* mas já da pra fazer umas brincadeiras. Caso tenham outra alternativa melhor para o que quero, fiquem a vontade para sugerir.

Comment: A melhor dica que eu posso dar é não tenha medo de exposição de código, você não é o único que consegue programar uma idéia, pior ainda mais se sua extensão nem é conhecida e não é possível ganhar dinheiro com ela. Trabalhe com o GitHub, é uma técnica de registro de direitos autorais que funciona muito, e outros podem te auxiliar futuramente. Foque em Firefox e outros, Chrome será desativado.

Comment: Sério que o navegador será desativado?

Comment: Ah não ser o Chrome do Android, o navegador brevemente vai parar de receber algumas atualizações importantes, é normal que as pessoas comessem a usar o Firefox

Comment: Há um equivoco quanto ***Chrome será desativado***, na verdade o que vai ser desativado são as **extensões**.